# Can I connect a router to another router to extend my connection?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I recently purchased a WHR-HP-300N, and have a question about connecting it to a WHR-G300N.

I have a computer that's about 20-30 feet from the router. I have a wireless USB adapter but it doesn't work that well, so I thought I would look at another option. The WHR-G300N can act as an access point correct? **So could I connect  the G300N to the HP300N and connect my desktop to the G300N via an Ethernet cable?** Basically I want the G300N to act as my 'wireless card' for the desktop that is 20-30 feet away from the HP300N that's connected to the modem, so I thought this option would be better than buying a USB stick.

But I want to make sure I can connect that desktop via an ethernet cable to the access point, the G300N. I am using a wireless N network.

This is what I'm trying to do, not sure what it's called, but curious if I can do something like this. Router #1 is the WHR-HP-300N and #2 is the WHR-G300N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing involves the the G300N acting as a wireless "bridge."  I am more familiar with Linksys routers, but I assume these are similar.

Plug your desktop into the G300N with an Ethernet cable.  Ensure that the "WAN" or "Internet" port is not connected to anything.  Set both wireless devices to use the same SSID so that they form one network.  Ensure that the G300N has its DHCP server turned off, as you do not want two DHCP servers active at the same time.

That should be all you need to do.  They should pass traffic between themselves automatically.

This is a question with tips on [setting up multiple wireless access points on the same network](https://serverfault.com/questions/63910/setting-up-multiple-wireless-access-points-on-same-network) that will help you.

Comment: does this 'halve' the traffic like a WDS does?? What kind of data rates can I expect with my Wireless N network between the two?

Comment: No, I would expect to get the full N speed from it.